# Adding a custom view to a storyboard crashes when IBOutlets are nil

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift, xib

I have a view controller that is referenced by a view built in **Storyboard**, In the storyboard I have added a `UIView` and set it's class to my new custom `PreviewView`.

`PreviewView` is built in a `xib` and has two `UILabels` and an `UIImageView`. These subviews are hooked up to the `IBOutlets` in the `PreviewView` class.

the PreviewView looks like this

```
class PreviewView: UIView {    

    @IBOutlet strong var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet strong var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet strong var priceLabel: UILabel!

    func populate(address: String, price: Int, imageUrl:NSURL){
        self.addressLabel.text = address
        self.priceLabel.text = "\(price) kr"

        self.imageView.setImageWithURL(imageUrl)
    }
}
```

When calling `populate` on a button tap in the `view controller` the app crashes on `self.addressLabel.text = address` as `self.addressLabel` is `nil`

Have tried similar code in objective C and have not the same issue there. Is this a Swift issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't add the UIView in Storyboard add it as a new File within an xib file in your project

Comment: It's added as a xib file in the project. It's still added to the actual view in the storyboard at use in the view controller.

Comment: I do not want to instantiate it in code but have storyboard load it from the xib as worked just fine before swift.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually issue of inheritance, when using below outlets in sub class

```
 @IBOutlet strong var imageView: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet strong var addressLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet strong var priceLabel: UILabel!
```

These outlet should be connected to sub class too.